# I am getting 500 internal server error ,in POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to get password from database when user enters username .I am doing it through JQUERY ajax .When I am trying to run the request on postman I am getting 500 internal server error.
This is my .aspx code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm4.aspx.cs" Inherits="Codefirstapproachtry.WebForm4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/getpassword.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
          <div>
            
            <asp:TextBox ID="dirtext" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="dirsubmit" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="dirsubmit_Click" />
           

              <br />
              <br />
              <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
           

        </div> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my .js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   
  

    $('#dirsubmit').click(function () {
    var objuser = {
        name: $('#dirtext').val(),

    };

    var param = {
        user: objuser
    };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm4.aspx/GetPassList1",
            data: JSON.stringify(param),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Hi");
                console.log(response);
                var result = JSON.parse(response.d);
                if (result.Status == 1) {
                    alert(result.Message);
                   
                }

            },
            error: function (response) {
                toastr.error("ajax error", "error");
            }
        });
});
});
```

And this is my GetPassList1 function which I am calling through JQUERY ajax

```
public static string GetPassList1(User user)
        {


            using (var db = new userdetailsDBContext())
            {

               
                var queryStud = db.UserDetails.Where(s => s.name == user.name)
                                              .Select(s => new { s.pass });
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryStud);
                


            }
        }
```

This is the data I am providing on Postman

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "Pragya"
       
    }
}
```

And I am getting 500 internal server error

Comment: there is nothing here that tells us what the server is doing. You are getting a server error when you call the endpoint so we need to see that code. Nothing from your front end will cause an internal server error.

Comment: The endpoint is WebForm4.aspx/GetPassList1.The code of GetPassList1 is given above. Please specify some other code if needed.

Comment: Why would you _ever_ want to return a password to the front-end? Passwords should be hashed and salted to begin with, so not even your application should know the password, let alone the front-end. You might want to go over OWASP's [Authentication Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.html) and [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html)